# URL alias error

Tags: path-aliases

I want to configure the URL alias patterns on my site. When I try visiting the `http://localhost/mysite/admin/config/search/path/patterns,` I get an error saying "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."
 All other paths work fine with the exception of the above. Any ideas on what could possibly be the course?

Comment: Is anything present in reports ? http://localhost/mysite/admin/reports/dblog

Comment: there is nothing in the reports

Comment: I have the same issue.
The report message is:


 Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to
 _token_token_tree_format_row() must be of the type array, string given, called in
 /.../sites/all/modules/token/token.pages.inc
 on line 130 and defined в функции _token_token_tree_format_row()
 (line 179 in file
 /.../sites/all/modules/token/token.pages.inc).


Any ideas?

Comment: The unexpected error usually means that the actual error is supressed by the server settings. Have you updated the token module in major version recently? Have you run the update.php script?

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is due to the php memory being set too low.

Instead of increasing for the entire site, you could target the specific page by adding this to the settings.php file in your sites folder.

if (isset($_GET['q']) && strpos($_GET['q'], 'admin/config/search/path/patterns') === 0) {
  ini_set('memory_limit', '512M'); 
}